# Remove Duplicates and Filter Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a simulator that has a marketplace where providers put offers and consumers bid. The concept is rather simple.

Based on consumers and providers offers and preferences, I create a dataframe sorted by the Euclidean distance between the consumer preference and the provider offer to maximize the consumer utility. This is one example: (the last column is not part of the dataframe)

```
   consumerId providerId capacity     price   quality  distance
9        1003       2001        1  0.815317  0.814237  0.769884  <-
4        1002       2001        1  0.815317  0.814237  0.586566  dup p,q
8        1003       2000        1  0.278722  0.064698  0.551566  dup Id
14       1003       2002        1  0.342255  0.069247  0.488291  dup Id
6        1003       2000        1  0.710141  0.503366  0.474249  dup Id
12       1003       2002        1  0.386136  0.062411  0.444144  dup Id
20       1005       2001        1  0.815317  0.814237  0.402990  dup p,q
13       1003       2002        1  0.467643  0.073472  0.363433  dup Id
15       1003       2002        1  0.527181  0.192858  0.337139  dup Id
21       1005       2002        1  0.951580  0.761860  0.319450  <-
7        1003       2000        1  0.611682  0.267618  0.312109  dup Id
1        1002       2000        1  0.710141  0.503366  0.310783  <-
5        1003       2000        1  0.725587  0.334001  0.307735  dup Id
17       1004       2000        1  0.710141  0.503366  0.305369  dup p,q
19       1005       2000        1  0.710141  0.503366  0.269010  dup Id
2        1002       2000        1  0.611682  0.267618  0.247648  dup Id
10       1003       2001        1  0.619495  0.082655  0.213857  dup Id
11       1003       2001        1  0.654035  0.163907  0.212591  dup Id
18       1004       2000        1  0.611682  0.267618  0.205169  <-
3        1002       2000        1  0.843739  0.410850  0.182180  dup Id
0        1002       2000        1  0.725587  0.334001  0.167611  dup Id
16       1004       2000        1  0.725587  0.334001  0.146053  dup Id
22       1009       2000        1  0.710141  0.503366  0.071535  dup p,q
```

Consumers can only buy one offer. Offers can only be bought once. I need to remove duplicates from the dataframe above, resulting on the follow:

```
   consumerId providerId capacity     price   quality  distance
9        1003       2001        1  0.815317  0.814237  0.769884
21       1005       2002        1  0.951580  0.761860  0.319450
3        1002       2000        1  0.843739  0.410850  0.182180
18       1004       2000        1  0.611682  0.267618  0.205169
```

The closest I got from doing this is by using `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['price', 'quality'], keep='first')` then to the same to remove duplicate `consumerId`.

However, this method would not include the last line 
`18       1004       2000        1  0.611682  0.267618  0.205169`
 since that offer would been removed from the first dedup operation.

What's the best way to accomplish this filtering?

Answer (score 0):

So I solved my issue by creating a new dataframe, iterating through each row, adding to the new df, and deduplicating at each step:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
    for idx, row in offers.iterrows():
        df = df.append(row)
        df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['consumerId'], keep='first')
        df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['price', 'quality'], keep='first')
```